# What is the common verb that expresses a person tries to convince children to follow them or do something bad?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

My daughter is about 7 and I want to train her to take the public bus to school (not a school bus because the school doesn't have a school bus) by herself. But the problem is that I am afraid some bad people might convince her to follow them or do dodgy things like doing drugs or joining a gang.

The common phrase is "**do not talk to strangers**".

But I want to make it clearer why not to talk to strangers.

What is the common verb that expresses a person tries to convince children to follow them or do something bad?

For example, "**do not talk to strangers as they might tempt/entice/lure... you into doing bad things or kidnap you**"

Comment: I'm sure you don't *really* want to explain exactly ***why*** to your daughter. Most parents wouldn't want their 7-year-old child to need to know all the sordid details of pedophiles and psychopaths.

Comment: English does have a number of "specially for **children**" words for genitalia, bodily waste functions, etc. And *in extremis* we can euphemistically use words like "cuddle", "tickle", "play" for sexual activity. But we don't have special "child-oriented" euphemisms for interfering with a minor.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S. we refer to people who do bad things to children as *predators*.  The term is also used to refer to anyone who takes advantage of someone weaker or more desperate than themselves.

So you might say, *Don't talk to strangers.  They could be **predators.***

You could use the verb *prey* but the noun *predator* is the more common way to refer to predators.  Of course, as Fumble Fingers points out, the follow-up question from the child will probably be, *What's a predator, Mommy?*  Good luck with all that.

Comment: "Predator" refers almost exclusively to people who commit sexual abuse, doesn't it?

Comment: @alphabet - In reference to children, it's often used and understood that way but it is not limited to that.  People who prey on any weaker group are *predators*,  Dictionary dot com definition #2.